# Are we only supposed to document common practices?

Tags: discussion, documentation, scope

I thought the current "Hello World" HTML example was bloated. It was also the only example in its topic, so I decided to write another [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/217/introduction-to-html/16696/minimal-hello-world#t=20160802053506117) example of a basic HTML document. Soon after, it was edited to include the phrase:

> However, as of this writing, the practice of excluding optional tags, which the browser will fill in anyway, is not common in production websites or applications. The practice is also not typically taught.

Following that, my example was met with an improvement request:

> Other: Why is this useful at all? When would someone ever recommend another person *actually create a page like this*? This isn't code golf - no one cares what the tiniest page you can create is. If there's no useful reason to do this, then it shouldn't be mentioned at all.
>
> This example is completely unclear, incomplete, or has severe formatting problems. It is unlikely to be salvageable through editing and should be removed.

Soon after, it was deleted with the comment:

> Unnecessary and not useful documentation, seems to be a sort of edge case better suited to a stack overflow query like the referenced one.

Now, I genuinely think this is a good practice, I linked to the Google style guide recommending it, and I actually write all of my HTML like this because I find it clearer, since the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags add two extra levels of indentation and don't really convey any information. My entire reason for creating the example was the hope that it would expose more people to this uncommon method of writing HTML.

A major theme of these "improvements" to my example is that they felt the practice was uncommon or an "edge case," and therefore the example should be changed to reflect that (or removed as not worth mentioning). So my question is, **should we only be documenting "common" practice?** This is one example, but this kind of logic could surely be applied elsewhere, similar to how [using an enum as a singleton in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/155/enums/5741/implement-singleton-pattern-with-a-single-element-enum#t=201608021002140814511) isn't really common, but has a number of advantages worth mentioning.

**If** we are supposed to be documenting obscure practices, then what went wrong here? I made a "Hello World" example because the HTML tags involved make up the majority of one. Was there a more appropriate topic to place this information? Should I have merged this example into the already existing one? What is the proper way to go about documenting this?

Comment: Though I personally disagree with the removal, I think their argument wasn't that it was uncommon practice. In their eyes it was *bad* practice.

Comment: *"was the hope that it would expose more people to this uncommon method of writing HTML."* That's a problem. I've this same thing in the C documentation as well.  People are using documentation to promote their own personal styles, rather than actually documenting how the language was intended to be used. Certainly, the "hello, world" example is not the place to try to expose more people to uncommon methods. And my opinion is that documentation shouldn't be used for that at all.

Comment: "When would someone ever recommend another person actually create a page like this?" As you have already mentioned, when that someone is Google. The fact that they have an entire style guide that says to prematurely optimize all the things is evidence enough. Having said that, how often does one *need* to optimize their markup that way? It's only bloated because HTML (and, worse, XHTML) is bloated by nature.

Comment: So maybe yours is an example of a "Hello World" which complies with the guide you linked to.  Make it more explicit, and post it in a different topic, where it does make sense?  I'm not familiar enough with HTML on Documentation to say where that is, but "Minification" sounds like a place where it could fit nicely.

Comment: do people actually still write html? i write code that writes it for me.

Comment: That is not how anyone writes a "hello world" example. That is how someone writes for a *specific* reason when you need as small of code as possible for some unique performance scenario (like when you work at Google). So no, your example was not appropriate for a general introductory section. This is so obvious I cannot believe I had to write the comment. Note that we've had this discussion before when someone tried to write a "hello world" example in C (or was it C++?) using streams. No one writes "hello world" with streams. You've written a topic/example on streams. Or on minification.

Comment: Minifying HTML is best left to a minifier

Answer (score 7):

As the comment above indicates, it was most likely deleted because people consider it poor practice. In any case, it's not something that belonged in the introduction. It may have a place elsewhere, but the introduction should essentially be an answer to: *I'm a beginner to X. How do I get started with it?*

When tags are unclosed, it complicates things. From [here:](https://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/quirks-mode.html)

> **Tag soup parsing.** For example, if a document contains the markup
>
> ```
> <p>text<table>...</table>
> ```
>
> then e.g. Firefox treats, in Quirks Mode, the p element as containing the table element. In Standards Mode, the start tag of table implicitly closes the open p element. The difference can be seen if you e.g. set a border on the p element. Similarly, for example, Firefox accepts a ul element inside a font element. IE always works by wrong rules in such issues, even in Standards Mode, but standards-conforming behavior can be achieved by using valid markup and always using explicit end tags like `</p>` even when they are formally optional.

If you actually read the [one link](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml#Optional_Tags) you had, it says:

> Omit optional tags (optional).
>
> For file size optimization and scannability purposes, consider omitting optional tags. The HTML5 specification defines what tags can be omitted.
>
> (This approach may require a grace period to be established as a wider guideline as it’s significantly different from what web developers are typically taught. For consistency and simplicity reasons it’s best served omitting all optional tags, not just a selection.)

I'm pretty certain that one does not run into "file size" or "scannability" problems when first starting out.

---

Uncommon practices may have a place elsewhere. I would include the information about which tags are optional in a place where those tags are discussed in detail.

Comment: While I appreciate the perspective this answer brings, I dislike that it focuses on the missing </p> tag, which was very much **not** the point of the example, and could just as easily have been included or edited in. The example then solely becomes about the missing `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags. Surely excluding _these_ can't be considered a poor practice? As a beginner, readability/scannability was one of my primary issues with HTML. This also avoids the question of what the proper documentation method is, since the introduction topic **is** where these tags are discussed in detail.

Comment: @RyanHilbert, *I* consider it bad practice to omit the `<html>` and `<body>` tags, though I've no problem with omitting empty `<head>` tags.  I don't claim that to be any kind of consensus (and I never even saw your example), but it seems entirely plausible to me that it would indeed be the prevailing opinion.

Comment: @RyanHilbert The Google style guide indicates that would be inconsistent. I did a bit more research, and it appears to be [invalid to omit those tags in ISO HTML.](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/minimal-html).

Comment: @Laurel The example is HTML5, not ISO HTML. It's perfectly valid HTML5, but I agree that it doesn't belong in a Hello World example for beginners.

Comment: @John Bollinger: I have to admit, that's the first time I've heard of anyone having different views on omitting <html>, <body>, and <head>.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that "best practice" be mentioned as such wherever appropriate.  Further, in the new "documentation" section, there should be a strong push to emphasize best practice in examples, discussion, etc.

Stylistic differences (eg, what and how far to indent) should not have one labeled as 'best'.

I am distinguishing "best" from "common" practice.  "Common" sounds like a lot of people do it, not that it is necessarily "best".  It seems reasonable to say "People *commonly* do ..., but it would be *better* to do ...".

This thread seems to talk a lot about HTML, which has so many sloppinesses (such as whether `<p>` needs "closing") and so many inconsistent implementations (such as what to do with various syntax errors) as to be an abomination of a language.  Hence it is almost impossible to say what is "best".

Comment: The effect of omitting html, head and body tags is well-defined in HTML5; there isn't room for it to vary between implementations. (If it does vary between implementations, then some of those implementations don't actually support HTML5)

Answer (score -6):

Well i do think that having an Hello World sample and a sample with google really specific guidelines along together just doesn't fit.

An Hello World is a minimal example written to be the more readable possible for very new users.

At the opposite, following google guideline just lead to the opposite side, it's less readable and are for experimented users that know why they need to do this. And following those guidelines is pretty much only usefull to google or really heavy traffic site that need this.

Your sample will probably fits better in a `performance` topic for web pages.

To answer to your question : "should we only be documenting common practice ?".

The answer in my opinion is **Yes and No"

Yes in majority :

In most of the topics, following best practices is just the best and will result of having code sample posted by different users to follow the same guidelines, which make it easier to read.

No for common errors and specific case

Best practices don't fit everywhere, this is specially the case when you deal with performance, where you may need to twick a bit your code to have something better.

Finally sometimes, i think it can just be better to document common errors, that have been answered many times on SO for instance, and the common fix that goes along with it.